# Error Deploying ASP.NET Core Web Application + ReactJS to Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core-2.1

Trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core Web Application  + ReactJS to Azure and the Publish step in my pipeline always ends in error – “Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1”

My pipeline is composed of:

```
Prepare job
Initialize job
Checkout
Restore
npm install (step added by me after some errors)
npm audit fix (step added by me after some errors)
npm run build (step added by me after some errors)
Build
Test
Publish <- Error!
Publish Artifact
Post-job: Checkout
Finalize Job
```

The error I get in the Pusblish step is:‌

```
===
Webpack compilation mode: production ===‌

 (…)
      Hash: c2e1b3f9437a24e5157e
      Time: 108142ms
      Built at: 05/09/2019 1:13:13 PM
               Asset      Size 
Chunks             Chunk Names

      main-server.js  3.58 MiB      
0  [emitted]  main-server
      Entrypoint main-server = main-server.js
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(141,5):
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file
"D:\a\1\s\wwwroot\dist\main-client.js.map" because it was not found.
[D:\a\1\s\nextvision.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(141,5):
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file
"D:\a\1\s\wwwroot\dist\vendor.css.map" because it was not found.
[D:\a\1\s\nextvision.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(141,5):
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file
"D:\a\1\s\wwwroot\dist\vendor.js.map" because it was not found.
[D:\a\1\s\nextvision.csproj]

##[error]Error:
The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

##[error]Dotnet
command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects :
D:\a\1\s\nextvision.csproj

##[section]Finishing:
Publish
```

Using “npm run build:prod” I thought the *.map files were not even necessary, but that is the only error I see on the Publish step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Pedro Cabral

Comment: did you create react files using visual studio 2017 or 2015?

Comment: We used vs2017.

Comment: Visual studio 2017 creates .map files which are redundant. Create react files outside vs 17, maybe use vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove npm publish step and try again. The npm publish step might be failing because the `private` property in package.json is set to true.

Try the Publish artifacts step and give the generated artifacts path ( `drop` or `build` folder) to the publish path step.